# Why I get this infinite-calling-cycle?

Tags: jquery, firefox, twitter

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/kgBGN/2/) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<a id="renderPI" href="javascript:void(0);">Render Plugin</a>

$('#renderPI').click(function () {
    new TWTR.Widget({
        version: 2,
        type: 'profile',
        rpp: 4,
        interval: 30000,
        width: 650,
        height: 202,
        theme: {
            shell: {
                background: '#7ee1fc',
                color: '#2e2e2e'
            },
            tweets: {
                background: '#ffffff',
                color: '#949494',
                links: '#009ece'
            }
        },
        features: {
            scrollbar: true,
            loop: false,
            vlive: false,
            hashtags: true,
            timestamp: true,
            avatars: false,
            behavior: 'all'
        }
    }).render().setUser('google').start();    
});
```

when I try to render the Twitter Widget, if you check the JS console, you see the strange bahaviour! Why? And how can I fix it?

**EDIT** Seems the problem is only on firefox? I get tons of `attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope` message...

Comment: No strange behavior here. What browser are you seeing it in?

Comment: I see this: "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope" is this the strange behaviour you are talking about? (Firefox & firebug)

Comment: Yes PoweRoy...and it still to call that function... and the widget is it not showed up...

Comment: Oh my god! Notice that this happens only on Firefox...(10)...arghh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twitter widget uses `document.write` statements. Doing a `document.write` on a page that is *loaded* empties the document hence the error -- [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/qkTBj/1/). My two cents: FireFox is doing the right thing.

The workaround is to tell the TWTR widget to avoid document.write and instead use DOM manipulation. Just create an empty DIV and pass its id as the `id` parameter to the TWTR widget -- [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/qkTBj/2/).

Comment: You save my day :) Thank you! Also : why your example works without http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js? :O

Comment: It _does_ require twitter widget; look at the left hand column in the fiddle under the manage resources section (or view source the result frame).

Comment: Well, didn't see that section before! Thank you...all is perfect! Unfortunatly this way doesnt get some CSS styles in the widget, on IE7+, strange...

Comment: Seems like the widget is unable to create `<style>` elements in IE. Try specifying background colors using CSS/jQuery.