# Iframe without src - Can I do it?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe

I'd like to make another "context" into my html page. Such as a page loaded by iframe. Now, what I'd like to do is use this iframe but without src.

Somethings like :

```
 <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:300px; height:20px;">
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <div>
                Hello World
            </div>            
        </body>    
     </html>
</iframe>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I need this because I wont use ajax and I need a load a script that could make some problems in the same page-context (as I [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772906/why-i-get-this-infinite-calling-cycle) yesterday on SO).

Comment: I answered your other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is impossible :(, the only way to create a separate html file.

Source: http://stackprogramer.com/7276457/is-it-possible-to-create-iframe-without-src-but-with-my-html